# Perl Net::Telnet waitfor Method Not Timing Out as Expected

Tags: perl, network-programming, telnet, netcat

I'm using Perl's `Net::Telnet` module to connect to a server and wait for a specific command prompt. However, I'm facing an issue where the `waitfor` method seems to get stuck indefinitely, even though I've specified a timeout. Here's the complete script that reproduces the problem:

```
use Net::Telnet;

# Replace with actual host and port
my $host = 'your_host_here';
my $port = 'your_port_here';
my $attempt_timeout = 15;  # Adjust as needed

my $t = Net::Telnet->new(Timeout => 30);
$t->errmode('return');

# Attempt to open a Telnet session
eval {
    $t->open(Host => $host, Port => $port);
};
if ($@) {
    die "Failed to connect: $@\n";
}

# Waiting for the command prompt - this is where it gets stuck
eval {
    $t->waitfor(Match => '/Command:.*$/', Timeout => $attempt_timeout);
};
if ($@) {
    die "waitfor method failed: $@\n";
} else {
    print "Command prompt received successfully.\n";
}

# Closing the session
$t->close();
```

When I run this script, it doesn't time out as expected at the waitfor step. Here are some details:

- The host and port are correctly set (verified).
- The regular expression in Match seems correct.
- Network connectivity doesn't appear to be an issue.

I'm curious as to why the timeout isn't working. Is this a known issue with `Net::Telnet`, or am I missing something in the implementation? Any help or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @toolic It seems that the command isn’t timing out as expected within the specified period. Shouldn't it timeout even if it doesn't match the match string, or in case of a network issue?

Comment: Try passing named parameters instead: $t->waitfor(-match => '/Command:.*$/', -timeout => $attempt_timeout)

Comment: @koo aren't they equivalent ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I quickly looked up the documentation and I couldn't find a single example where 'Match' or 'Timeout' are used as actual keys (besides in waitfor()'s signature); however I DID find at least one example where '-match' and '-timeout' are used instead, so I thought it was worth a shot; if that happens to work, it might be that 'Match' and 'Timeout' are simply unrecognized and are ultimately causing the halt, AKA documentation bug (or lack of clarity thereof). Just something worth trying because otherwise everything else seems correct to me.